# Typescript & SystemJS: customize module resolution for a specific extension

Tags: typescript, module, systemjs

I use `SystemJS` and `typescript 2.0.2` to develop my application.

**systemjs.config.js**

```
var map = {
    'app':   'dist',
};

var packages = {
    'app':  { main: './main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

So when I use:

```
import {Services} from './service.module'

//result: load {baseURL}/dist/service.module.js
```

How can I overwrite this behavior and get the compiler to *not* append any extension for a specific file?  For instance if I do:

```
import htmlTemplate from './app.component.html';

//result: 404 Not found - {baseURL}/dist/app.component.html.js
```

On the other hand, if I use absolute path:

```
import htmlTemplate from 'app.component.html';

//result: 404 Not found - {baseURL}/app.component.html
```

I'd like `{baseURL}/dist/app.component.html` without having to use the full path in the `import`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that systemjs by itself can not load html. I use [systemjs-plugin-text](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text) for that:

```
npm install systemjs-plugin-text
```

Then, this config works for me:

```
var map = {
    'app':   'dist',
    'plugin-text': 'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-text/text.js'
};

var packages = {
    'app':  {
        main: './m1.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: { '*.html' : { loader: 'plugin-text' }}
    }
};

SystemJS.config({
    map: map,
    packages: packages
});
```

because apparently `loader`, when it applies, overrides any other setting in package config.

**NOTE1** this will work only if `module` in typescript compilerOptions is set to `system`.

**NOTE2** for the HTML import to typecheck with typescript 2.0, you have to add this [wildcard ambient declaration](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#wildcard-character-in-module-names) to `declarations.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "*.html" {
    const templateString: String;
    export default templateString;
}
```

I added example repo on [github](https://github.com/fictitious/example-typescript-systemjs-html-import)

Comment: Hi artem. Thanks for your feedback. I've stumbled upon the same solution, but I still cannot apply the result of `import htmlTemplate from 'app.component.html'` into my component's `template` metadata, even though I know `systemjs-plugin-text` is being used.  Checkout my post here for details: https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text/issues/40

Comment: It looks like it's working only when you set `"module": "system"` in tsconfig.json. I added [example](https://github.com/fictitious/example-typescript-systemjs-html-import) on github and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Artem. I gave a fuller reply on github, but you were absolutely right. Took me a while to get up the courage to make the change but once I did, things worked.

Comment: By the way, the module declaration can be much simpler: `declare module "*.html"` is sufficient as of `typescript 2`